# No Line Found Error (java.util.NoSuchElementException)

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to handle multiple exceptions in my code, while using the Scanner to let the user enter a new path if the current one is incorrect, however I keep getting the same error, "No Line Found". Any help would be appreciated. The problem is occurring in the catch blocks at "path = sc.nextLine()".

```
public class Deck {

    private static ArrayList<Card> monsters = new ArrayList<Card>();
    private static ArrayList<Card> spells = new ArrayList<Card>();
    private ArrayList<Card> deck = new ArrayList<Card>();
    private static String monstersPath = "Database-Monster.csv";
    private static String spellsPath = "Database-Spells.csv";

    // private static Board board;

    public Deck() throws IOException, UnknownCardTypeException,
            UnknownSpellCardException, MissingFieldException,
            EmptyFieldException {
        if (monsters== null) {
            monsters = loadCardsFromFile(monstersPath);
        }
        if (spells == null) {
            spells = loadCardsFromFile(spellsPath);
        }
        // shuffleDeck();
        buildDeck(monsters, spells);
        shuffleDeck();
    }

    /*
     * public static Board getBoard() { return board; }
     * 
     * public static void setBoard(Board board) { Deck.board = board; }
     */

    public ArrayList<Card> loadCardsFromFile(String path) throws IOException,
            UnknownCardTypeException, UnknownSpellCardException,
            MissingFieldException, EmptyFieldException {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int trials = 3;
        String currentLine = null;
        //String newPath = "";
        for (int i = 0; i <=trials ; i++) {
            try {


                FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(path);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
                ArrayList<Card> temp = new ArrayList<Card>();
                int sourceLineNumber = 1; // Source line
                while ((currentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    String[] mOrS = new String[6]; // Monsters or Spells
                    mOrS = currentLine.split(",");
                    int sourceFieldNumber = 0;
                    while (sourceFieldNumber < mOrS.length) {
                        if (mOrS[sourceFieldNumber].equals("")
                                || mOrS[sourceFieldNumber].equals(" ")) {
                            throw new EmptyFieldException(path,
                                    sourceLineNumber, sourceFieldNumber + 1); // Depends
                                                                                // on
                                                                                // the
                                                                                // Splitted
                                                                                // String
                                                                                // array,
                                                                                // loop
                                                                                // on
                                                                                // every
                                                                                // field
                                                                                // and
                                                                                // check
                        }
                        sourceFieldNumber++;
                    }

                    if (mOrS[0].equals("Monster")) {
                        if (mOrS.length == 6) {
                            int attack = (int) (Integer.parseInt(mOrS[3]));
                            int defense = (int) (Integer.parseInt(mOrS[4]));
                            int level = (int) (Integer.parseInt(mOrS[5]));
                            MonsterCard monster = new MonsterCard(mOrS[1],
                                    mOrS[2], level, attack, defense);
                            temp.add(monster);
                        } else {
                            throw new MissingFieldException(path,
                                    sourceLineNumber); // Depends on the amount
                                                        // of fields in the
                                                        // String array, Monster
                                                        // should have 6, Type
                                                        // and 5 attributes.
                        }
                    } else if (mOrS[0].equals("Spell")) {
                        if (mOrS.length != 3) {
                            throw new MissingFieldException(path,
                                    sourceLineNumber); // Depends on the amount
                                                        // of fields in the
                                                        // String Array, Spells
                                                        // should have 3, Type
                                                        // and 2 attributes
                        }
                        if (mOrS[1].equals("Card Destruction")) {
                            CardDestruction cardDestruction = new CardDestruction(
                                    mOrS[1], mOrS[2]);
                            temp.add(cardDestruction);
                        } else if (mOrS[1].equals("Change Of Heart")) {
                            ChangeOfHeart changeOfHeart = new ChangeOfHeart(
                                    mOrS[1], mOrS[2]);
                            temp.add(changeOfHeart);
                        } else if (mOrS[1].equals("Dark Hole")) {
                            DarkHole darkHole = new DarkHole(mOrS[1], mOrS[2]);
                            temp.add(darkHole);
                        } else if (mOrS[1].equals("Graceful Dice")) {
                            GracefulDice gracefulDice = new GracefulDice(
                                    mOrS[1], mOrS[2]);
                            temp.add(gracefulDice);
                        } else if (mOrS[1].equals("Harpie's Feather Duster")) {
                            HarpieFeatherDuster harpieFeatherDuster = new HarpieFeatherDuster(
                                    mOrS[1], mOrS[2]);
                            temp.add(harpieFeatherDuster);
                        } else if (mOrS[1].equals("Heavy Storm")) {
                            HeavyStorm heavyStorm = new HeavyStorm(mOrS[1],
                                    mOrS[2]);
                            temp.add(heavyStorm);
                        } else if (mOrS[1].equals("Mage Power")) {
                            MagePower magePower = new MagePower(mOrS[1],
                                    mOrS[2]);
                            temp.add(magePower);
                        } else if (mOrS[1].equals("Monster Reborn")) {
                            MonsterReborn monsterReborn = new MonsterReborn(
                                    mOrS[1], mOrS[2]);
                            temp.add(monsterReborn);
                        } else if (mOrS[1].equals("Pot of Greed")) {
                            PotOfGreed potOfGreed = new PotOfGreed(mOrS[1],
                                    mOrS[2]);
                            temp.add(potOfGreed);
                        } else if (mOrS[1].equals("Raigeki")) {
                            Raigeki raigeki = new Raigeki(mOrS[1], mOrS[2]);
                            temp.add(raigeki);
                        } else {
                            throw new UnknownSpellCardException(path,
                                    sourceLineNumber, mOrS[1]); // We have 10
                                                                // spells, if
                                                                // there is an
                                                                // unknown one
                                                                // we throw the
                                                                // exception
                        }
                    } // else of Spell code
                    else {
                        throw new UnknownCardTypeException(path,
                                sourceLineNumber, mOrS[0]); // We have two
                                                            // types, Monster
                                                            // and Spell.
                    }
                    sourceLineNumber++;
                }// While loop close
                br.close();
                return temp;
            }// try Close
            catch (FileNotFoundException exception) {
                if (i == 3) {
                    throw exception;
                }
                System.out
                        .println("The file was not found, Please enter a correct path:");
                path = sc.nextLine();
                //path = newPath;
            } catch (MissingFieldException exception) {
                if (i == 3) {
                    throw exception;
                }
                System.out.print("The file path: " + exception.getSourceFile()
                        + "At Line" + exception.getSourceLine()
                        + "Contians a missing Field");
                System.out.print("Enter New Path");
                path = sc.nextLine();
                //path = newPath;
            } catch (EmptyFieldException exception) {
                if (i == 3) {
                    throw exception;
                }
                System.out.println("The file path" + exception.getSourceFile()
                        + "At Line" + exception.getSourceLine() + "At field"
                        + exception.getSourceField()
                        + "Contains an Empty Field");
                System.out.println("Enter New Path");
                path = sc.nextLine();
                //path = newPath;
            } catch (UnknownCardTypeException exception) {
                if (i == 3) {
                    throw exception;
                }
                System.out.println("The file path:" + exception.getSourceFile()
                        + "At Line" + exception.getSourceLine()
                        + "Contains an Unknown Type"
                        + exception.getUnknownType());
                System.out.println("Enter New Path");
                path = sc.nextLine();
                //path = newPath;
            } catch (UnknownSpellCardException exception) {
                if (i == 3) {
                    throw exception;
                }
                System.out.println("The file Path" + exception.getSourceFile()
                        + "At Line" + exception.getSourceLine()
                        + "Contains an Unknown Spell"
                        + exception.getUnknownSpell());
                System.out.println("Enter New Path");
                path = sc.nextLine();
                //path = newPath;
            }
        } // For loop close
        ArrayList<Card> noHope = null;
        return noHope;
    }// Method Close
```

Comment: I assume you're using a similar `Scanner` in a different class or method and you're closing that scanner there. Please check that and if this is the case, then remove the `#close()` call.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `hasNext()` before assigning `path = sc.nextLine();`

Something like :-

```
if (sc.hasNext()){
    path = sc.nextLine();
}
else{
    //print something else.
}
```

[next](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next%28%29)

> public String next() Finds and returns the next complete token from
>   this scanner. A complete token is preceded and followed by input that
>   matches the delimiter pattern. This method may block while waiting for
>   input to scan, even if a previous invocation of hasNext() returned
>   true. Specified by: next in interface Iterator Returns: the
>   next token Throws: NoSuchElementException - if no more tokens are
>   available IllegalStateException - if this scanner is closed See Also:
>   Iterator

Comment: I already tried that, but to no avail. Another thing, When I run, I get an error saying that the source is not found, saying The source attachment does not contain the source for the file Scanner.class. What does that mean? I'm sorry if the question is dumb, I'm still a beginner.

Comment: You shouldn't check with `#hasNext` if you like to use `#nextLine`, use `#hasNextLine` instead. And there is no need to check that if the Scanner reads from `System.in`, because there is always something to read from there (if the stream isn't closed).

Comment: I've fixed said error, tried a different route with my constructor and that seemed to fix it. Thanks for all the suggestions.